# Can Anyone Identify This Japanese Rock Song in the Background of this Mika Nakashima Video?

Tags: identify-this-song, rock, japan

[Link to Mika Nakashima video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H95vVg_d9g4#t=5m53s)
This is a personal video of Mika Nakajima (中島 美嘉) towards the beginning of her fabulous career (2002).  The song in question starts here at 5:53.  I'm pretty sure the song is not hers as it's not her style - it's rather upbeat rock with a female lead vocalist.  The video is dated Jul-2002 but who knows how old the song might be.  I'd really like to get the song/CD so if anyone out there recognizes it, you'd really be helping me sleep at night.  I've been inquiring about it on various sites on and off for over 5 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is [Siva 1999](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPY1IomX9Jg) by [Sugar Soul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_Soul) feat. Zeebra.

I found this song using [midomi](https://www.midomi.com/).

Comment: Amazing - iyudamaan!  (I'll have to try out this midomi.)

Comment: @squidlydeux Glad to help! :-) Hey, if you have a couple of minutes, please, take a look at [my question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/10572/uncredited-song-from-the-movie-the-informer-2019).